# Media Queries ignored - safari/opera

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries, opera

I am having an issue with what I believe is my media queries.  They are being ignored by Safari and opera, however work on Chome and firefox.  This is causing the pages to look different on chrome and firefox, vs opera and safari.

I have made sure to include the meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and my queries look like this:

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), and (max-width:1170px) {}`

I am very perplexed, as this is straight HTML/CSS.  No JS etc involved at this point.  I have added a link to a codepen containing the project below: http://codepen.io/cgraffeo/pen/ryGzXG

On opera and safari this happens, as you can see it pushes things all over the place:  [image]

Comment: I've removed the (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) from the media query as it was breaking chrome/firefox and did not resolve the issue.  The issue still exists.

Comment: There is some situations not supported for a common browsers and you may check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20query) to check availability. I think of no present solution yet.

Comment: Thank you for the response, before starting the project I checked caniuse.com.  Let me know if you think of anything, I'm wondering if there is another issue that I just am not seeing.

Comment: Well, I have tried a couple of ways for one of my projects as a matter of fact, and then had to quit insisting on it since like I'm the only one trying to solve it! Happy for you if you can find a workaround but it's a known thing issued many times still not easily adaptad to main browsers by producers yet.

Comment: Alright man Thank you for trying.  I ended up building it in a different way using bootstrap and such.